# MotionLayout apply loadLayoutDescription

Tags: android-motionlayout

I have 2 different behaviours for MotionLayout. The idea is to change them based on application state. But when i'm setting from code:

```
if(smth) {
   constraintToolbar.loadLayoutDescription(R.xml.layout_description_1)
} else {
   constraintToolbar.loadLayoutDescription(R.xml.layout_description_2)
}
```

Constraints are not applied. But they are applied after drag motion. Is there some workaround or it's because of ConstraintLayout 2.0.0 alpha ?
I'm using:

```
'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha2'
```

Answer (score 2):

I have  transition in MotionScene.

```
<Transition
    motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@id/end"
    motion:duration="1000"
    motion:interpolator="linear">
```

Initial constraint is not setted after "MotionLayout.loadLayoutDescription". 
I added:

```
MotionLayout.setTransition(R.id.start, R.id.end)
```

and constrains applied correctly.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a workaround, but does work

```
if(smth) {
   constraintToolbar.loadLayoutDescription(R.xml.layout_description_1)
   constraintToolbar.setTransition(R.id.start1, R.id.end1)
} else {
   constraintToolbar.loadLayoutDescription(R.xml.layout_description_2)
   constraintToolbar.setTransition(R.id.start2, R.id.end2)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you must set transactions after load layouts.

```
        if(smth) {
            constraintToolbar.loadLayoutDescription(R.xml.layout_description_1)
            motionContainer.setTransition(R.id.start1 ,R.id.end1)

        } else {
            constraintToolbar.loadLayoutDescription(R.xml.layout_description_2)
            motionContainer.setTransition(R.id.start1, R.id.end1)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`loadLayoutDescription` I think just use in `androidx`

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha2'
```

or if u not using androidx you must change constraintToolbar to motion

```
val motion = MotionLayout(this)

motion.loadLayoutDescription
```

Answer (score 0):

aftere called

```
if(smth) {
   constraintToolbar.loadLayoutDescription(R.xml.layout_description_1)
} else {
   constraintToolbar.loadLayoutDescription(R.xml.layout_description_2)
}
```

invoke `motionLayout.requestlayout()` to let the new MotionScene work.

> Note: the first <Transitoin .../> in <MotionScene .../> would be work.

Answer (score 0):

For me this works

```
    doOnPreDraw {
        motionLayout.loadLayoutDescription(R.xml.scene)
    }
```